# Load rasters with for loop without dialog box

Tags: qgis, raster

I am trying to load many rasters (pngs in this case) using a for loop but for each raster loaded the "Coordinate Reference System Selector" dialog box pops up and I have to hit OK.  I have specified the CRS for each layer within the loop. How can I avoid the dialogue box?

```
import os
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo,QSettings

s = QSettings()
oldValidation = s.value( '/Projections/defaultBehaviour' )
s.setValue( '/Projections/defaultBehaviour', 'useGlobal' )

path = '/path/to/my/files/'
files = os.listdir(path)
pngs = [path + f for f in files if f.endswith('.png')]

for png in pngs:

    name = png.split('.')[0].rsplit('/')[-1].rstrip('1234567890_').partition('ave_')
    name = name[0] + name[-1]
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(png,name)
    rlayer.setCrs( QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId) )

s.setValue( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour", oldValidation )
```

The code imports the rasters, but it requires me to sit there and click the button in the box each time, which is obviously undesirable.
Thanks.